# CXF Webservice does not generate complex types for all classes

Tags: spring, soap, cxf

I have built a CXF+Spring Web service using Eclipse running on Tomcat7. The web service works except that it does not create a complex type from one of my classes.

My Eclipse project is called: "ws-server". In the buildpath I have added API-A, API-A-Impl and API-B.

The buildpath is correct. All libraries are deploying as they should. The wsdl is created but there is no complex types from API-B they (only one class, Page, in API-B).

In the wsdl the Page class is defined like this in other complex types.

```
<xs:complexType name="getAllMeasuremenetObjectsByPage">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="page"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="orderBy" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="orderDirection" type="tns:orderDirection"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I'm not sure where to start looking. It feels like there is something with CXF. I don't think there is anything wrong with the Eclipse project configuration. All other methods in the web service that does not have the "page" argument works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solution!

CXF Does not generate complex type from java objects that does not have a constructor without arguments.